# File upload with Behat, Mink & PhantomJS

Tags: selenium, file-upload, phantomjs, behat, mink

I am trying to upload a file using Behat. Therefore I wrote this simple HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and a simple Behat feature:

```
Feature: test
  Scenario: Some Test
    Given I am on "/upload.php"
    And I attach the file "/path/to/tile" to "file"
```

When the `I attach the file ... to ...` phrase is executed, the selenium 2 driver generates a curl request and sends it to PhantomJS: `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/5b9a8630-ed8e-11e4-956f-956a9ce75127/element/:wdc:1430215640681/value with params: {"value":["\/path\/to\/file"]}`

The request does not terminate unless aborting it and PhantomJS does not react on the request in any way.

I already searched through the net and found several threads saying that it does work and several saying that does not work including an issue on github (https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/282) which was closed and reopend multiple times.

Versions:
PhantomJS: 2.0.0
Behat: 3.0.15
Mink: 1.6.1
Mink-Selenium2-Driver: 1.2.0

Does anyone know a working solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this behaviour exist due to inability to upload files that is a [known bug](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12506) with PhantomJS v 2.0.0?

> Basically, a change made in Qt 4.8 and incorporated subsequently in Qt 5.0 prevented clicking on file input elements that were not caused by user gestures.

The solution is discussed [further in the issue thread](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12506#issuecomment-61698339).

To quote, you have to comment one if condition in
**/src/qt/qtwebkit/Source/WebCore/html/FileInputType.cpp**

```
//if (!ScriptController::processingUserGesture())
//    return;
```

then compile the binary.

Comment: Totally forgot about this post. Yes you are right. It's the PhantomJS bug.